# how to checkout only specific folder from git repo and build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hey folks I need some help on the jenkinsfile. Below is my usecase

This is the strcuture of my GIT repo:

```
root
  |->app1
  |   |->jenkinsfile
  |   |->dockerfile
  |->app2
      |->jenkinsfile
      |->dockerfile
```

I am having a monorepo, app1 and app2 in the root folder and I want when their is a change in app1 folder, only app1 should build and same for app2. I have defined the jenkinsfile in jenkins but when its build. its looking for dockerfile1 in root folder not inside app1.

jenkisfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT = true
        DEVPI_USER = '\'jenkins_user\''
        DEVPI_PASSWORD = '\'V$5_Z%Bf-:mJ\''
        WORKSPACE="${WORKSPACE}/app1"

    }
    stages {
        stage('Notify Bitbucket') {
            steps {
                bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'INPROGRESS')
            }
        }

        stage('Build Environment') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t app-builder .'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {

            steps{
                sh 'docker run --rm app-builder pytest'
            }
        }
```

Comment: use changesets. + in the jenkins job setup for either app give the correct location of the jenkins file.

Comment: @marxmacher: I am giving the correct jenkinsfile location. it still searching for deckerfile in root directory

Comment: can you add some of your jenkinsfile here. otherwise its hard to guide you.

Comment: @marxmacher: added the jenkinsfile

Comment: Does explicitly specifying `PATH` to dockerfile to look at it helps?, with - like in : `sh 'docker build -t app-builder -f ${WORKSPACE}/app1/'`

Comment: @gamechanger17 you can cd into the right folder or use the dir command.

Comment: can you share the job configuration? on your pipeline you don't have any code that will make us think that the jenkinsfile will be chosen dynamically depending on which folder was updated.

Comment: @matus: I am using the multibranch pipleline, there you have option to specify the subfolder change.

Comment: @marxmacher: That will solve the problem but I have to cd for each command for every stage. Is there any way we can change the directory for all stages at once?
even if I use 'dir', it will change the directly for 1 stage.

Comment: @VikasRathore not that i know of...

Answer (score 0):

Use [dir](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) command to change the directory e.g

```
stage('Build Environment') {
   steps {
      dir("app1"){
         sh 'docker build -t app-builder .'
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem with the dir is you have to use each time for every stages.

Answer (score 0):

On a multi-branch pipeline, you could leverage the `customWorkspace` option of the [jenkins agents](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)

The change you are making to the `WORKSPACE` env variable affects the variable only, it does not change the workspace location.

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        node {
            label 'my-node'
            customWorkspace '${WORKSPACE}/app1'
        }
    }

    environment {
        PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT = true
        DEVPI_USER = '\'jenkins_user\''
        DEVPI_PASSWORD = '\'V$5_Z%Bf-:mJ\''
    }
```

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for. I'll test if this really change the workspace if yes than I'll accept this an answer. thanks a lot

Comment: I afraid it will checkout the whole repo into the `${WORKSPACE}/app1`. @VikasRathore I'll be glad to know if it has worked as expected

Comment: @yuri-g, you can use the agent definition for the whole pipeline (as is shown in the above example) or just for a single stage ... https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent ... so you can make the change to an agent with a customWorkspace after the initial steps are performed (eg. checkout)

Comment: @matus the checkout happens after workspace is allocated. See the ticket https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41118 for more details. So neither  global `customWorkspace` nor single stage `customWorkspace` won't resolve the issue. You can use `ws` in every single stage, but in this case you need to use it each time for every stages. I would just delete the unneeded code and move the needed app into the workspace root.

Answer (score 0):

The `git` plugin allows to define **sparse checkout paths**. You can use this to restrict the directories in your clone.